# How can i create a partially nested array?

Tags: javascript

I have a question with multiple answers. I want an array that has two spots, the first can only hold one value (one question), the second can hold an array (multiple answers).

Question: 'favorite colors'
Answers: 'blue' 'black' 'red'

```
var answer = [];
var question [[],answer];
```

I'm unable to get this to work properly. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you wanted?

```
var question = 'What is your favourite color?';
var answers = ['blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'pink', 'omg, ponies!'];

var your_array = [question, answers];
```

or without immediate variables:

```
var your_array = [
    'What is your favourite color?', // question here
    ['blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'pink', 'omg, ponies!'] // answers array here
];
```

To get the question you do:

```
var your_question = your_array[0];
```

To get the list (array) of answers you do:

```
var your_answers = your_array[1];
```

Comment: how would i pick the second choice(yellow) in the array? just your_array[1][1]?

Comment: @user1082764: To get the second answer you will need to do it like that: `your_array[1][1]`. Its because the arrays are indexed beginning with `0` (zero), and this array is multidimensional. The first dimension choses answers (`your_array[1]`) that lie on the second position (thus `[1]`), and the second dimension choses second position within what you get so far (so the second position within the answers).

Comment: I am struggling a to understand multidimentional arrays, you've been great help!

Comment: @user1082764: Good to know. If it helps, you can treat every part with brackets separately (because it is how it works). `your_array[1][1]` really means: 1) `your_array` means "_get `your_array` variable_", 2) `[1]` means "_get second element of what you got so far, from point 1)_", 3) the second `[1]` means "_get the second element of what you got so far, from point 2)_".

Answer (score 3):

```
 var list = [ 'favorite colors', ['red','black'] ];
```

But I would do something like this instead:

```
 var question = { question: 'Favorite color',
   answers: ['red','black']
 }

 var list = [ question, ... ];
```

Comment: this is very interesting, do i need to var list{question:'favorite color',answers:['red','black']}

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var question =  [[], answer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

```
var question = [[],answer];
```